# Align along inequality sign

Tags: horizontal-alignment

```
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2} \geq \frac{1}{2^k} \\
\frac{3}{2} \geq 1 + \frac{1}{2^k} \\
\frac{3}{2} -  \frac{1}{2^k} \geq 1 \\
\frac{3}{2} - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2^k} \geq 1
\end{align}
```

How do I align each inequality along the inequality signs?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX!  You just have to add an ampersand before the alignment points.

Comment: `align` requires you to mark the alignment points, put a `&` before the `\geq`

Answer (score 2):

you need to add anchors -- ampersands before inequality signs:

[image]

mwe:

```
\documentclass[12pt,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}                                 & \geq \frac{1}{2^k} \\
\frac{3}{2}                                 & \geq 1 + \frac{1}{2^k} \\
\frac{3}{2} -  \frac{1}{2^k}                & \geq 1 \\
\frac{3}{2} - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2^k}   & \geq 1
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```